# Filtering joins with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 table, named as

```
students (id, name)
subjects (id, name, is_published)
student_subjects (id, student_id, subject_id)
```

The subjects taken by a student goes in `student_subjects`. But there are cases where student_subjects contains `NULL subject_id` for a student

Here's the data for `Students` table

```
1;"John"
2;"Ahmeah"
3;"Dina"
4;"Leo"
5;"Lenon"
```

Subjects Table

```
1;"Computer Sci";1
2;"Physics";1
3;"Bio";1
4;"Maths";0
```

Student_subjects

```
1;1;1
2;1;2
3;1;4
4;2;1
5;2;3
6;2;4
7;3;2
8;4;1
9;5;NULL
```

Currently to fetch all the students with their subjects and also display the name of the student who has no subject attached to him, I am using the query as follows

```
SELECT
  students.*,
  inners.name
FROM
  students
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                student_id,
                subjects.name
              FROM
              student_subjects
              JOIN subjects ON ( student_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id AND subjects.is_published = 1)
              ) AS inners ON (inners.student_id = students.id )
```

Is there a better way to do the same http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9cf93/12

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.*, su.name AS SubjName
FROM students AS s
LEFT JOIN student_subjects AS ss ON ss.student_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN subjects AS su ON su.id = ss.subject_id
```

Does the same thing as the one you listed. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Sorry, I seemd to have missed the condition in the query of (subjects.is_published = 1)

Comment: You can add it by moifying one line as follows: `LEFT JOIN subjects AS su ON su.id = ss.subject_id AND su.is_published = 1`

Comment: this would not work, as this would also display all those students who are not attached in student_subjects